# I want to store image into remote database

Tags: php

I have tried and also found some server side coding for this. I don't know what to write in client side. I want to store the image on image view to remote database.

```
<?php
    $host="localhost"; // Host name
    $username="root"; // Mysql username
    $password=""; // Mysql password
    $db_name="q"; // Database name
    \
    // Connect to server and select databse.
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    // username and password sent from form     $myusername=$_GET['ID'];
    //$mypassword=$_GET['email'];
    $target1="Login/".$_FILES['sr']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['sr']['tmp_name'], $target1);
    //$passport=$target1;
    $fe=$_FILES['sr']['name'];

    $qu="INSERT INTO q(q)VALUES('$fe')";
    $res=mysql_query($qu);
    if($qu) {
        echo "success";
    }
    else {
        echo "mahender".mysql_error();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? What's your question?

Comment: I want to do it by ios not by html.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a form to your php file in client side.

```
<form action="your_php_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="sr" accept="image/*">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some notes about code **Security**:

- Your PHP code is completely unprotected. Be careful about that and
  try to divide your code by modules.  Possible SQL Injection with
  Filename on your query.
- Don't forget to sanitize inputs (as in that case, filename, filesize, file format...)
- You should create a Hash (SHA1, MD5...) using your file's name and use it to store your file on your files path and on your database entry

Now refering to the client side of the file uploader, check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.